# RegEx - Split Every Charachter Unless #N?

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I'm looking to individually split a string into individual characters, except sequences of digits shouldn't be split, and digits followed by `n` shouldn't be `split`

So `4h12u/o15n` would be split into:

```
4
h
12
u
/
o
15n
```

I've tried several things and it hasn't worked.

```
(?!\dn)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `split`, you need to specify the separator. There is no actual separator in this case, so `split` is not the best tool for the job. A regex match is.

```
my @a = /\d+n?|./g;
```

Doesn't mean it can't be done using `split`.

```
# Between non-digit and following digit, and
# Between digit and following non-digit other than "n".
my @a = split /(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\dn])/;
```

Knowing that `split` doesn't try to split at the beginning of the string, and knowing that `split` removes empty trailing fields by default, the above can be simplified to

```
my @a = split /(?<!\d)|(?!\dn)/;
```

Comment: (`\d` matches over 400 characters, but I suspect your input is ASCII, of which it only matches `0` to `9`.)

Comment: I've been using /(?<!\d)|(?!x)/s and I thought it was working perfectly, but it will split up instances such as 10n into 1 and 0n instead of leaving it intact.

Comment: This is the first time you mentioned it shouldn't split between digits. Adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to split with this pattern:

```
(?:^|(?<=\d)n|$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|
```

The combo of backtracking control verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` forces the pattern to fail and to not retry positions on the left. `(*SKIP)` means *if the pattern fails, do not retry all that have been matched on my left*. `(*FAIL)` forces to fail.

But there is a more simple way: Do not split at all!

You can obtain the same result with a simple global research with:

```
\dn|.
```

A more conventional way with split:

```
(?<=\d)(?!n|$)|(?<!\d|^)(?=n)|(?<!\d|^)(?!n|$)
```

Comment: @ikegami: Not so absurde since you copy one of the pattern in your own answer.

Comment: Yes, it's good that you mentioned the better solution, but what's with the two split solutions you gave?!

Comment: And no, I didn't copy anything from you. I had no read past the first paragraph of your answer when I wrote my answer.

Comment: I haven't excuse to ask to anyone, but I think that your problem is out of the scope of SO

Comment: Other interesting comments?

Comment: @ikegami: But what do you want? I'm not your psy, find other people for this kind of things

Comment: @ikegami: Nobody here must be accountable to you. If you think you have a better way, write it in your own answer, but don't use comments to promote it.

Comment: @ikegami: no, I'm not

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(?<!\d)|(?!n)
```

This will split at every position that *either* does not follow a digit, *or* does not precede an 'n'.

Comment: This works, except in scenarios when there is more than 1 digit before 'n'. For instance, 10n gets split into 1 and 0n